# Pass arguments as alias for creating Kafka topics

Tags: terminal, macos

I would like to create Kafka topic with partitions and repliocation number using alias:

```
alias tcreate='bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --topic "$@" --partitions "$@" --replication-factor "$@" --zookeeper localhost:2181'
```

When I run the command `tcreate 1 1` , I get the following message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Only one of --bootstrap-server or --zookeeper must be specified
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$TopicCommandOptions.checkArgs(TopicCommand.scala:743)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$.main(TopicCommand.scala:53)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand.main(TopicCommand.scala)
```

How do make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using bash, you should check the [GNU Bash reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html#Special-Parameters):

> ($@) Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one.

Also, aliases can't get positional parameters. Instead, you should use [functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Functions.html#Shell-Functions) with proper [positional parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Positional-Parameters.html).

This is what you should define:

```
tcreate(){
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --topic "$1" --partitions "$2" --replication-factor "$3" --zookeeper localhost:2181
}
```

so that each argument is replaced on their specific place in the command. I'd also recommend to use full paths for shell script files, because relative paths depend highly on the current directory and the function will only work in a specific current directory.

Also, your example command `tcreate 1 1`  would also create an error because the third parameter is missing, in case you typed it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This is what works for me:

```
alias ktc='f(){ bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --topic "$1" --partitions "$2" --replication-factor "$3" --zookeeper localhost:2181;  unset -f f; }; f'
```

Then I provided the command in terminal:

```
$ ktc t_name  1 1
```